# Exclude Redundant Wildcards (SQL)

Tags: sql, pattern-matching

This is not a difficult problem to solve, but it doesn't seem to have been asked on the site so I thought I should post it

**Sample Data:**

| wildcard |
| --- |
| %abc% |
| abc |
| something abc% |
| ijk |
| this is mno |
| %mno% |

**Expected Output:**

| wildcard |
| --- |
| %abc% |
| ijk |
| %mno% |

**Problem Statement:**

List all wildcards except those that are redundant. For e.g. whatever matches with `this is mno` would match with `%mno%`, making the former redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it easier to solve using `not exists`

```
with cte(wildcard) as

(select '%abc%' union all
 select 'abc' union all
 select 'something abc%' union all
 select 'ijk' union all
 select 'this is mno' union all
 select '%mno%')

select *
from cte a
where not exists(select *
                 from cte b
                 where a.wildcard <> b.wildcard and 
                       a.wildcard like b.wildcard)
```